# Windows Command To Get Inactive Users Passed 90 Days

Tags: windows, powershell, command

I am trying to craft a command on Windows that searches for user accounts that have been inactive for more than 90 days.

The command below works:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90.00:00:00 | Format-Table Name,ObjectClass -A
```

However, this requires installing AD components for the "Search-ADAccount" parameter to work. Is there a way of getting this information without the need to install any additional components?

Comment: using ADSI but, I strongly suggest against it. Not user friendly at all. Why not install the Active Directory Module? You may even have better luck with Quest Active Directory Module/Snap-in.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I need to run that check on a few machines and installing additional modules is not allowed, I've been searching for alternative methods but it all seems to lead down the path of installing modules :/ I'm trying to get this information for local user accounts.

Comment: Why would you need to install them on the remote machines? Arent you on a Domain Environment? Are you searching local accounts?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Yes, I'm trying to search for local accounts.

Comment: You can try Net User, it returns some useful info such as the last logon time for the users

Comment: If you’re trying to get info on local accounts, why would you be doing anything in AD? Search-ADAccount, has AD right in its name. Get-localuser, get-localgroup, get-localgroupmember are included in ps5 and up

Comment: that's where i was confused too lol

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Thank you, would you know of a way of querying accounts that have been inactive for longer than 90 days using that command?

Comment: Yeah I agree with @DougMaurer you already have native PS5.1 cmdlets for that. There is no such thing as "inactive local accounts", thats an AD attribute / construct. You can however search for "Disabled" local accounts `Get-LocalUser|where{-not $_.Enabled}`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Apologies for the confusion :)

Comment: So did their suggestions help you?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Thank you very much for the feedback, really appreciate it. The command you have share is very useful, although I would have liked to do a test against accounts inactive for more than 90 days.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment, you can do something along the lines of this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeLine=$true,
                   HelpMessage='Enter Computer Name')]
                   [Alias('CN','Computer')]
                   [string[]]$ComputerName)
 Process{
     try{
        Foreach($Computer in $ComputerName){
            $UNC  = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$ComputerName\c$\Users" -ErrorAction Stop
            
                Foreach($user in $UNC.name){
                   $UserDate = (net user $user /domain | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Last Logon" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).Split(' ') 2>&1 | Select-Object -Skip 20 -First 1 
                            [PSCustomObject] @{
                                "User Name"   = $user
                                "Last Logon"  = $UserDate
                                    }
                                }
                            } 
                        }Catch{
                            [PSCustomObject] @{
                                "User Name"   = $user
                                "Last Logon"  = $null

                        }
                    }
                }
```

If you're looking for specific users, `Net User` should do the trick, but against a list of users that have logged into a machine, the above script can give you some feed back for that.

Im just confused on the local accounts part of this, are they actual local accounts, or Domain Accounts?

Comment: Thank you so much, only looking for local user accounts.